# How to seamlessly use jython classes and methods from an IPython interpreter?

Tags: python, subprocess, ipython, jython, interpreter

In an attempt to seamlessly use jython methods and classes in an IPython interpreter, I came up with a lot of twisted ideas and tried:

- to just change the `sys.executable` to point to a jython interpreter. This fails when importing Java packages, since `sys.path_hooks` misses `org.python.core.JavaImporter` that jython uses to load them.
- to write a decorator for my module's functions. The whole idea is:

  - at the beginning of `test_module`, test if the current interpreter is jython or not by setting the following flag: `withjython = 'jython' in sys.executable`
  - decorate function `test_function` with decorator `@create_jython_decorator(withjython)`, the code of which is:

    ```
    def create_jython_decorator(withjython):
    def call_with_jython(function_to_wrap):
        def jython_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            if not withjython:
                args_str = ', '.join(map(str, args)+map(lambda (kw, arg) : '='.join(map(str, (kw, arg))), kwargs.items()))
                command = ['jython',  '-c', 'from test_module import '+function_to_wrap.func_name+'; '+function_to_wrap.func_name+'('+args_str+')']
                return subprocess.call(command)
            else:
                return function_to_wrap(*args, **kwargs)
         return jython_wrapper
     return call_with_jython
    ```

  Thus, when calling a function `test_function` from an IPython interpreter, a `subprocess` call is issued that uses a jython interpreter to run the method. This works, but prevents me from retrieving the return value of my function if any, since there is no way I know to retrieve it on top of stdout or the return code.
- I attempted to define another module `jython_proxy` holding only a variable `_proxy`, but to no avail, since I found no way to have it survive the `subprocess` call.

  Schematically I added `import jython_proxy` at the beginning of `test_module` and used `jython_proxy._proxy = function_to_wrap(*args, **kwargs)` instead of `return function_to_wrap(*args, **kwargs)` in my decorator. This does not work because I guess using `subprocess` spawns an entirely different python session with no connection to my current session.

At this stage, I am sure that either the jython interpreter or using my module as a script will definitely be enough to suit my needs. I am also aware that there is an `IPython` module with methods such as `embed` or `start_ipython` that could do the trick. Anyway, I had a lot of fun in my attempts, and I am eager to know if there would be a way.

Comment: The obvious approach seems to be to just install and run IPython on Jython. Did that work?